# Why one function are giving diffrent errors in Python

Tags: python-3.x, vector, linear-algebra, data-science

This is an assignment in Udacity linear algebra refresher course and I have solved it in my way although there is a solution available for this assignment I am trying to solve it in my way.  But I am getting error while finding angle between 2 vector  that is vectore v1 and v2 .

There is 2 problems  asked 2 solve to this program. But even if there  is same. but  to programs is giving to diffrent out put  even if there "angle" function is same.

```
import math 
from decimal import Decimal,getcontext
getcontext().prec = 30
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self,coordinates):
        try:
            if not coordinates:
                raise ValueError
                #if coordinates is not passed then it will rise Value Error 
            self.coordinates = tuple([Decimal(x)for x in coordinates])
            #Outside Class :-Vector.coordinates will give print vectors in tuple form
            #Inside Class :- self.coordinates will print vectors in tuple form
            self.dimension = len(coordinates)
            #Outside Class :-Vector.dimension will print vectors dimension/size
            #Inside Class :- self.dimension will print vectors dimension/size
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('The coordinates must be non empty')
        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('The coordinates must be itterable')
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector:{}'.format(self,coordinates)
    def __eq__(self,v):
        return self.coordinates == v.coordinates
    def add (self,v):
        coordinates=[]
        for i in range(0,self.dimension):
            i=self.coordinates[i]+v.coordinates[i]
            coordinates.append(i)
        return coordinates

    def mul(self,v):
        coordinates=[]
        for i in range(0,self.dimension):
            i=self.coordinates[i]*v.coordinates[i]
            coordinates.append(i)
        return coordinates

    def sub (self,v):
        coordinates=[]
        for i in range(0,self.dimension):
            i=self.coordinates[i]-v.coordinates[i]
            coordinates.append(i)
        return coordinates

    def scal_mul(self,s):
        coordinates=[]
        for i in self.coordinates:
            i=i*Decimal(s)
            coordinates.append(i)
        return coordinates
    def magnitude(self):
        mag = 0
        for i in self.coordinates:
            i=i*i
            mag =mag+i
        return math.sqrt(mag)

    def magnitude1(self):
        mag = 0
        coordinate_squre=[i*i for i in self.coordinates]
        return math.sqrt(sum(coordinate_squre))

#     def normalize(self):
#         try:
#             recip = Decimal(1)/self.magnitude()
#             return Vector(self.scal_mul(recip))
#         except ZeroDivisionError:
#             raise Exception("Can not Normalize Zero Vector")

    def normalize(self):
        try:
            recip = 1/self.magnitude()
            return self.scal_mul(recip)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            raise Exception("Can not Normalize Zero Vector")


    def dot_product(self,v):
        mul = self.mul(v)
        return sum(mul)

    def dot_product2(self,v):
        self.mul = [x*y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates,v.coordinates)]
        return sum(self.mul)
    #-----------------angle functionn is giving wrong answer-------------
    def angle_rad(self,v):
        norm = self.normalize()
        angle = 1/ math.cos(norm.dot_product2(v))
        return angle

    def angle(self,v,in_degree=False):
        nrm_self = self.normalize()
        nrm_v = v.normalize()
        angle_rad = math.acos(nrm_self.dot_product2(nrm_v))
        if in_degree:
            angle_in_degree = angle_rad * 180./math.pi
            return angle_in_degree
        else:
            return angle_rad

v1 = Vector([7.887,4.138])
v2 = Vector([-8.802,6.776])
print(v1.angle(v2))        
v1 = Vector([-7.579,-7.88])
v2 = Vector([22.737,23.64])
v2.angle(v1)
```

This Code is giving Error as following

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-2087e4f0ca26> in <module>()
    101 v1 = Vector([7.887,4.138])
    102 v2 = Vector([-8.802,6.776])
--> 103 print(v1.angle(v2))
    104 v1 = Vector([-7.579,-7.88])
    105 v2 = Vector([22.737,23.64])

<ipython-input-44-2087e4f0ca26> in angle(self, v, in_degree)
     92         nrm_self = self.normalize()
     93         nrm_v = v.normalize()
---> 94         angle_rad = math.acos(nrm_self.dot_product2(nrm_v))
     95         if in_degree:
     96             angle_in_degree = angle_rad * 180./math.pi

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dot_product2'
```

And another program with exactly same angle function is

```
import math 
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self,coordinates):
        try:
            if not coordinates:
                raise ValueError
                #if coordinates is not passed then it will rise Value Error 
            self.coordinates = tuple(coordinates)
            #Outside Class :-Vector.coordinates will give print vectors in tuple form
            #Inside Class :- self.coordinates will print vectors in tuple form
            self.dimension = len(coordinates)
            #Outside Class :-Vector.dimension will print vectors dimension/size
            #Inside Class :- self.dimension will print vectors dimension/size
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('The coordinates must be non empty')
        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('The coordinates must be itterable')
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector:{}'.format(self,coordinates)
    def __eq__(self,v):
        return self.coordinates == v.coordinates
    def add (self,v):
        coordinates=[]
        for i in range(0,self.dimension):
            i=self.coordinates[i]+v.coordinates[i]
            coordinates.append(i)
        return coordinates

    def mul(self,v):
        coordinates=[]
        for i in range(0,self.dimension):
            i=self.coordinates[i]*v.coordinates[i]
            coordinates.append(i)
        return coordinates

    def sub (self,v):
        coordinates=[]
        for i in range(0,self.dimension):
            i=self.coordinates[i]-v.coordinates[i]
            coordinates.append(i)
        return coordinates

    def scal_mul(self,s):
        coordinates=[]
        for i in self.coordinates:
            i=i*s
            coordinates.append(i)
        return coordinates
    def magnitude(self):
        mag = 0
        for i in self.coordinates:
            i=i*i
            mag =mag+i
        return math.sqrt(mag)

    def magnitude1(self):
        mag = 0
        coordinate_squre=[i*i for i in self.coordinates]
        return math.sqrt(sum(coordinate_squre))

    def normalize(self):
        try:
            recip = 1/self.magnitude()
            return Vector(self.scal_mul(recip))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            raise Exception("Can not Normalize Zero Vector")

    def dot_product(self,v):
        mul = self.mul(v)
        return sum(mul)

    def dot_product2(self,v):
        self.mul = [x*y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates,v.coordinates)]
        return sum(self.mul)
    #-----------------angle functionn is giving wrong answer-------------
    def angle_rad(self,v):
        norm = self.normalize()
        angle = 1/ math.cos(norm.dot_product2(v))
        return angle

    def angle(self,v,in_degree=False):
        nrm_self = self.normalize()
        nrm_v = v.normalize()
        angle_rad = math.acos(nrm_self.dot_product2(nrm_v))
        if in_degree:
            angle_in_degree = angle_rad * 180./math.pi
            return angle_in_degree
        else:
            return angle_rad


v1 = Vector([7.887,4.138])
v2 = Vector([-8.802,6.776])
print(v1.angle(v2))        
v1 = Vector([-7.579,-7.88])
v2 = Vector([22.737,23.64])
v2.angle(v1)
```

it is giving Error as following

```
2.0023426999774925

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-214-2e3bee12967a> in <module>()
     95 v1 = Vector([-7.579,-7.88])
     96 v2 = Vector([22.737,23.64])
---> 97 v2.angle(v1)
     98 

<ipython-input-214-2e3bee12967a> in angle(self, v, in_degree)
     82         nrm_self = self.normalize()
     83         nrm_v = v.normalize()
---> 84         angle_rad = math.acos(nrm_self.dot_product2(nrm_v))
     85         if in_degree:
     86             angle_in_degree = angle_rad * 180./math.pi

ValueError: math domain error
```

We can see they are having same angle function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your first program is that the normalize method returns a list of coordinates, `return self.scal_mul(recip)` but doesn't convert that list into a Vector object like the second program, which instead `return Vector(self.scal_mul(recip))`. When you call `nrm_self.dot_product2(nrm_v)`, the object nrm_self is a list, not a Vector, and it doesn't have a dot_product2 method. You need to add an explicit call to the constructor Vector(), like in the second program, to be able to invoke methods from the norm_self object.

The math domain error is being thrown because dot_product2 is returning a value larger than 1 (unfortunately, 1.0000000000000002), and the inverse cosine acos(x) is only defined for values between -1 and 1. This is due to numerical error in the normalization, and can be corrected by always rounding the reciprocal slightly up.

Comment: Hey thanx @JAustin  now I solved the problem of math domain error  using round function as follows ` def angle_rad(self,v):`
        norm = self.normalize()
        angle = 1/ math.cos(norm.dot_product2(v))
        return angle`